# Is it possible to get the value of a radio button that's not in a form in php?

Tags: php

I have 2 html forms, the first form is compulsory to fill in and the second one isn't.
Structure is as follows

```
<form name="form1" >
<!-- random input tags -->
</form>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="0" id="optionsRadios1" >
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="1" id="optionsRadios2" >
</div>

<form name="form2">
<!-- random input tags -->
</form>
```

What happens in my application is:

1. a user can fill in the first form and depending on which radio button is selected , the 2nd form can be filled in

I use jquery to show and hide the forms accordingly. But I need to use the optionsRadio value to know what queries to make to the database. I've searched the net and couldn't find anything on this. I thought long and hard and came to the conclusion that I could use 1 form and just hide certain fields depending on the radio selection (with jquery). But just out of curiosity, is it actually possible to get the value of optionsRadios in php even though its not in a form?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You could use a single form and hide/show options for the fields you want to be optional.

Comment: I'm curious as how you get the data from the second form if the first one is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to realize that the best way to do this is with a single form, with all inputs inside it. Right on.

To answer your literal question:

> Out of curiosity, is it actually possible to get the value of optionsRadios in php even though its not in a form?

The answer is no, it's not possible normally. The browser will not send the values to the server. However, you can submit the data via GET or POST to the server with javascript (technically you don't need a form at all).

Answer (score 0):

why using to forms? you could combine the forms and use divs to hide data from the screen. Its more handy, and that way you send all the data at once! Otherwise you should submit the first form (load a new page) and get the next form.

Answer (score -2):

If the name is unique, you could try using document.all.optionsRadios.value in javascript.
The .all. will pick up from anywhere in the document. 
Previous answer is good though. You would be better using one form and use divs with ids and inline styles to effectively add/remove parts of the form dynamically.
Cheers